# how to solve text captcha using python?

Tags: python-3.x, captcha

i am trying to solve a captcha :
[captcha image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoSaT.jpg)

i used a script to solve this :

```
import cv2
from pytesseract import image_to_string

img = cv2.imread("captcha2.jpg")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(h, w) = gry.shape[:2]
gry = cv2.resize(gry, (w*2, h*2))
cls = cv2.morphologyEx(gry, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, None)
thr = cv2.threshold(cls, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
txt = image_to_string(thr)   
print(txt)
```

but it givers me output like :

```
sj
p ou,

4
```

which is not correct, the required output must be:

```
psojky
```

can someone please tell me how to achieve this?